# Angular select - make option selected based on property

Tags: angularjs, select, properties, initialization

I have an array of subjects like:

```
`[
  { subject: 'Maths',   preferred_teacher: '00000'},
  { subject: 'Chemistry',   preferred_teacher: '11111'},
  { subject: 'Art',   preferred_teacher: ''}
]`
```

And an array of teachers:

```
[{name:'Farmer', _id: '00000'},{name:'Smith', _id: '11111'}]
```

I need to create a form, where I will produce a list of subjects with a dropdown (select) for each one, allowing to pick the preferred teacher. 
However, I don't know how I can make each (!) select initialized with Angular options show the presently selected preferred teacher.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I have failed to apply other answers to my case.

EDIT:

Added property _id to reflect my particular case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (updated based on OP edit):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.subjects = [
      {subject: 'Maths', preferred_teacher: '00000'},
      {subject: 'Chemistry', preferred_teacher: '11111'},
      {subject: 'Art', preferred_teacher: ''}
    ];
    $scope.teachers = [{name:'Farmer', _id: '00000'}, {name:'Smith', _id: '11111'}];
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Teacher</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="subject in subjects">
        <td><span ng-bind="subject.subject"></span></td>
        <td><select ng-model="subject.preferred_teacher"
                    ng-options="teacher._id as teacher.name for teacher in teachers">
            </select></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br> {{subjects}}
  </form>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Will try this on my system, just a moment!

Comment: Tim Harker, thank you for the working example! Would you be so kind and modify your snippet to be able to show the actual Teacher name in the dropdown, but match the property in Subjects array by the _id property? Please see edits I have made to the question –